# socket.io emit message from one namespace to another

Tags: socket.io, namespaces, emit

I'm trying to emit a message from one namespace to another (on connection).
Bellow is some sample code with how I was trying to approach it.

**[Server]**

```
// Namespaces
var users_ns = io.of('/users');
var machines_ns = io.of('/machines');

// Attempt to receive the event on the socket
users_ns.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('test', function(socket){
        console.log('socket test');
    });
});

// Attempt to receive the event on the namespace
users_ns.on('test', function(socket){
    console.log('namespace test');
});

// Emit an event to the 'users' namespace
machines_ns.on('connection', function(socket){
    users_ns.emit('test');
});
```

**[Client1]**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost/users');
```

**[Client2]**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost/machines');
```

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server code is correct, but some misunderstanding occurred.

**[server]**

```
// Namespaces
var users_ns = io.of('/users');
var machines_ns = io.of('/machines');

// Attempt to receive the event on the socket
users_ns.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('test', function(){
        console.log('socket test');
    });
});


// Emit an event to the 'users' namespace
machines_ns.on('connection', function(socket){
    users_ns.emit('test');
});
```

When you are broadcasting to users_ns sockets, this events received in client side, not in server sides. So this is correct client side code

**[Client1]**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost/users');
socket.on('test',function(){ alert('broadcast received');});
```

**[Client2]**

```
var socket = io('http://localhost/machines');
```

when one socket connect to machine namespace, all clients connected to users namespace will raise 'broadcast received' alert.

Comment: Great, many thanks for the reply! It makes total sense. My confusion was that I thought that the event should go through the other NS first before finally be emitted to the clients.